# Expected value for an empirical CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Given the following empirical CDF:

$$\hat{F}(x)= \begin{cases}
         0 & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
         0.4 & \text{if $ 0 \leq x < 1$} \\  
         0.8 & \text{if $ 1 \leq x < 2$} \\  
         1 & \text{if $x \geq 2$} 
\end{cases} $$

By definition, $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i=\int x \,d \hat{F}_X(x)$. However, the derivative of this CDF is everywhere zero so the PDF does not exist. I think that X is not continuous though the set of its values is in [0,2) and it is not countable. How can we obtain the expected value of this?

Comment: The PDF is the derivative of the CDF if the CDF is everywhere differentiable.

Comment: You need to keep track of when you use capital $X$ and when you use lower-case $x$.  I took the liberty of changing $\hat F_x(x)$ to $\hat F_X(x)$.  The meaning of these expressions should make it clear which should be which and why. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT** By inspection, we can see that the pmf of this distribution is 
$$
f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         0.4 & \mbox{if $x=0$} \\
         0.4 & \mbox{if $x=1$} \\  
         0.2 & \mbox{if $x=2$} \\
         0 & \mbox{elsewhere}
\end{array} \right. 
$$

Comment: Thank you. Then the expected value is 0*0.4 + 1*0.4 + 0.2*2 = 0.8? Can you please explain how you got this PDF. I don't see the connection.

Comment: When you find jumps in the CDF, that indicates a point mass (a point $x$ where $P(X=x)>0$).  What $P(X=x)$ is is the "size" of the jump in the CDF.

Comment: This is a pdf with respect to counting measure, not with respect to Lebesgue measure. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy perhaps you would like to provide a constructive contribution?

Comment: @hubert_farnsworth : Notice that for the function $f$ defined in this answer, you have $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^3 f(x)\,dx = 0$.  But if you integrate with respect to counting measure, then you get the appropriate probabilities.  Thus this is a probability MASS function.  To say it's a density without specifying that that is with respect to counting measure is potentially misleading. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for helping clarify this for hubert_farnsworth.  I'll admit my answer was rather informal, and to be honest my only education in probability/statistics is a calculus-based-undergraduate course.  I'd hate to bother you some more on this question, but would stating that this is a probability mass function in the answer help clear up the informality currently in my answer?

Comment: @Aweygan : That would clarify things. $\qquad$